# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource despite it is there

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have java application exposing its api as rest services. It is accessible on the following URL: http://localhost:8080
On the other hand I have Angular standalone client trying to call those services. This client is operating on different URL: http://localhost:8383

To avoid CORS issue I have added this to the response header of my rest services:

> return Response.ok(result,
>   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
>   "http://localhost:8080").build();

Now it appears no matter what I put as a value of this header:

- http://localhost:8080
- http://localhost:8383
- (* - star)

client doesn't work complaining for the lack of this header:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/PokerGame-REST. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed
>   access. (16:24:11:684 | error, javascript) at app/index.html

What is the problem here, did I miss something?

It's worth mentioning that Advanced REST client returns the response as expected and the response headers contain this one: Access-Control-Allow-Origin. So it looks like purly my Angular app issue but why?

Another interesting thing is client behavior. When I use:

> $http.get('http://localhost:8080/PokerGame-REST/').success(function
>   (response) { ... }

it fails with the error in question but when I use this:

> var restCall = $resource('http://localhost:8080/PokerGame-REST/', {});
>
> restCall.get(function (restResponse) {    $scope.intro = restResponse; });

it fails with different error:

> Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

which is not true as the response is purly in JSON format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified with the browser network tools that the HTTP response really does contain the headers?

Comment: Make sure that response to OPTIONS method contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header as well. `Preflight` request is an OPTIONS request which is sent before your real request. Also, maybe think of using a filter to add required header as mentioned here: https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/

Comment: Try sending 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in the header

Comment: So you'd have var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } then do $http.get(url, {headers:headers}).then etc...

Comment: Response headers from Google ARC:Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8383
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 20:25:30 GMT
Content-Length: 63

Comment: So it does contain that header

Comment: PJDef - you're right, that was the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PJDef was right (second comment) and his suggestion helped me to resolve the issue.